Craft Commerce Stripe Plugin exlude Amex Brand
My client want to disbale Amex as a payment brand on the Stripe Plugin for Craft Commerce - is this possible?
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/customize-payment-methods#filter-card-brands
https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe?tab=readme-ov-file#creating-a-stripe-payment-form
I see that Stripe have a product called 'Radar' that possibly does this, but can it be done with the Stripe Commerce plugin?
Many thank
